# Can not write to php file

Tags: php

I want to make new PHP file and add nav.php but nothing is written on the new file. Only 1 I don't know what it means.

```php
 <?php
 $video = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
 $vid_name = $_REQUEST["vid_name"];
 $php_name = $_REQUEST["php_name"];
 $title_page = $_REQUEST["title_page"];

 $vid_location = "klipove/";
 //move_uploaded_file($video, $vid_location);

 echo $php_name;
 $test = "sex-test.php";
 //Create new page
 file_put_contents($php_name, include "nav.php");

?>
```

Comment: `include("nav.php")` returns `1` because it was successfully included. do you want the contents of `nav.php` or the result of executing `nav.php` ?

Comment: I want the content. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "Only 1"?

Comment: I want to make easy new pages using input tag where I write the name of the new php file. Then I want to put the code from nav.php in it.I used fwrite and file_put_content but they only write 1 to the new file. Alaa gave me this code file_put_contents($php_name, file_get_contents("nav.php")); this works but i must change permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the contents:

replace `file_put_contents($php_name, include("nav.php"));` with `file_put_contents($php_name, file_get_contents("nav.php"));`

Note that contents means the code it self and will not be executed unless you include/require `$php_name` and `$php_name` must have `.php` suffix.

Comment: It gives me error Warning: file_put_contents(/teest.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/raichica/public_html/sendinfo.php on line 13

Comment: @Kamunro that means the webserver doesn't have permission to overwrite the file. Normally that's a good thing for security, the php server should not be able to overwrite existing code files as it could be used as an exploit by a hacker to try and insert malicious code into the application. Why are you trying to get PHP to save PHP files on the disk? What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? Certainly you should not write into the site root. Move the file to a subfolder where there is permissions, using move_uploaded_file, and never allow it to have a .php extension.

Comment: I want to make new pages without writing the same code each time for menu video player and other thanks for the help

Comment: @Kamunro that's what you use header and footer and template pages for. Or a CMS